# Сколько нужно времени чтобы стать python junior developer?

Tags: python

Я начинаю учить програмирование на Python но ещё совсем не понимаю сколько нужно уделять времени на программирование и за сколько времени можно достичь знаний на уровне джуна? Можете посоветовать с чего начинать или продолжать изучение языка программирования. В день пытаюсь тратить где-то от 2 до 4 часов на программирование. Проходила теорию по книгам "Программируем на Python" Доусона Майкла, также "Автоматизация рутинных задач с помощю Python". Может сможете посоветовать книги достойны прочтения. На что уделять больше времени и какие фреймворки изучать в дальнейшем?

Comment: Устройтесь на работу и будет вам куча полезных данных и материалов. Каждый фрейм ворк нужен для какой то конкретной цели. Нет смысла изучать, допустим, библиотеку для ботов телеграм, если хотите делать сайты или заниматься аналитикой данных. Да и в целом, "сколько времени" - это очень субъективный и индивидуальный показатель, как, скажем, сколько времени требуется что бы выучить стих? Будет 100 человек, будет 100 времен. А сколько перед ответом догадаются спросить - что за стих?

Comment: Я поняла ваше мнение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Джун - 1-3 года опыта. Работает под контролем. Нуждается в четких указаниях. Работает с кодом. Не видит большой картины. Работает над некритичным функционалом. Мотивирован и энергичен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]